# Using codeigniter like query with wildcard

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-like

I'm trying to use a `like` query on Codeigniter.  The function escapes my percent sign `%` to `\%`.

My query is:

```
SELECT *
        FROM (`invoices_rent`)
        WHERE `clerk_name` =  'BEAUTY'
        AND  `date`  LIKE '\%/\%/\%' 

$this->db->like('date', $date, 'none');
```

What can I do to prevent the percent sign getting escaped?

I'm trying to make a filter with the date where i can receive a number or the wildcard. So what i want is to join this data in a way that i can get the month, year or date that the user wants. So i would pass to the query "%/02/2015" or "%/%/2015" to return the data range that i need. But I'm having a problem with the escape on the function.
I think I'll need to create the entire query instead of using this CodeIgniter functions to make it. Follow the actual model function.

```
$date = "%/03/2015";

public function getallinvoices($type = false, $date = false, $clerk = false)
{
    if($type == "m")
        $table = "invoice_month";
    else
        $table = "invoices_rent";

    if($date != false)
        $this->db->like('date', $date, 'none');

    if($clerk != false && $clerk != "all")
        $this->db->where('clerk_name', $clerk);

    $query = $this->db->get($table);

    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    print_r($query);

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I want the query to return like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`invoices_rent`)
WHERE `clerk_name` =  'BEAUTY'
AND  `date`  LIKE '%/03/2015'
```

Comment: just to understand what you are saying. You use `$this->db->like('date', $date);` and your result is  `SELECT * FROM (invoices_rent) WHERE clerk_name = 'BEAUTY' AND  date LIKE '\%/\%/\%'` What is your expected result supposed to be like?

Comment: Can you provide your entire CI query? can you also provide the exact content of your `$date` variable?

Comment: Remove `none` as 3rd parameter. From docs: `If you do not want to use the wildcard (%) you can pass to the optional third argument the option 'none'. `

Comment: Do as @ParagTyagi suggests, if you need to format the current date, you can use `$now = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("now"))`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, i put a few more informations to help. Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do here.
Adding a 3rd parameter as `none` won't add wildcard `(%)` around the value (or it may `escape` them, in your case).

From **[docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)**:

> If you do not want to use the wildcard (%) you can pass to the optional third argument the option 'none'.
>   
> $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none'); 
>   // Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match'

Hence if you want to use wildcard, just **remove** the 3rd parameter.

**(just for your reference)**
Assuming table,

```
`invoices_rent`

id    rent    invoice_number    clerk_name     date
1     150        INV001           BEAUTY     2015-03-04
2     250        INV002           BEAUTY01   2015-02-05
3     350        INV003           BEAUTY     2015-03-04
```

Query,

```
$date = '2015-03-04';
$this->db->like('date', $date);
$this->db->where('clerk_name');
$query = $this->db->get('invoices_rent');

return $query->result();

/**
* Result will give id: 1 & 3 as output
*/
```

**EDIT:**

As per your updated question, basically you want all the rows of the month march, 2015. What you are trying is definitely not the right way to query when date ranges are in concerned. What you can do is like get the start of the month (for eg. 2014-03-01) and end of the month (2014-03-31) and use `between clause` and this will give you all the rows of the month March
Below will be your query.

```
$month_start = date('Y-m-01', 'March');   # Month's start
$month_end = date('Y-m-t', 'March');      # Month's end

$this->db->where('date >=', $month_start);
$this->db->where('date <=', $month_end);
$this->db->where('clerk_name');
$query = $this->db->get('invoices_rent');

return $query->result();

/**
* Result will give id: 1 & 3 as output
*/
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what OP was trying to achieve with the 3rd parameter either, but this was very well written.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to make a filter with the date where i can receive a number or this wildcard. So what i want is to join this data in a way that i can get the month, year or date that the user wants. So i would pass to the query "%/02/2015" or "%/%/2015" to return the data range that i need. But I'm having a problem with the escape on the function.

Comment: @ParagTyagi I'm trying to remake the query in the way you explained but the function to get the start and the end of the month returns: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please share the exact code you are using for start and end of the month.

Comment: @ParagTyagi I managed to create the date manually and now its working how it should. Thanks a lot mate